# Update multiple settings in a group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to disable External Sharing on an O365 Group. I will do that by setting following:

```
var content = new StringContent(@"
{
    'displayName': 'Group.Unified.Guest',
    'templateId': '08d542b9-071f-4e16-94b0-74abb372e3d9',
    'values': [                    
        {
            'name': 'AllowToAddGuests',
            'value': 'False'
        }
    ]
}'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var content2 = new StringContent(@"
{
    'displayName': 'Group.Unified',
    'templateId': '62375ab9-6b52-47ed-826b-58e47e0e304b',
    'values': [
        {
            'name': 'AllowGuestsToAccessGroups',
            'value': 'False'
        }
    ]
}'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

I can set the first one by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}/settings
```

But how do I set both settings? I get a bad request when adding both one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As per the settings update/patch specific group [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/groupsetting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-update-a-specific-group-setting) one can only update settings under one template at a time. Updating the settings across template Id's is not supported at this moment.